# Python Session scope across browser tabs

Tags: python, session, web.py

I'm using python web.py to create a quick prototype to test something. I noticed that the scope of the session variable is such that 2 tabs on the same browser, Chrome, for example, share the session.

Is there a way to avoid this? It would allow me to debug and test more efficiently.

To provide some context, I'm using `DiskStore` for sessions:

```
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All modern browsers behave this way.  It has to do with sending cookies to a site that has set the cookies previously.  If not, popups, and other windows would not be able to function correctly.

To get around this, I often use Incognito and Normal browsing in Chrome.  There is a separation there which prevents one from seeing the other's cookies.

Also, you can use separate browsers to accomplish this.

Comment: You can also run multiple distinct copies of Chrome by using the `--user-data-dir=` option.

Comment: Thanks. I kinda guessed that. Just wanted to confirm there isn't a faster way. Btw, I am using Firefox and Chrome for testing right now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187649/how-to-solve-webapp2-session-cookie-conflicts-between-browser-tabs

I solved it by creating my own session-id including a CSRF and saving this session-id in the form and not in a cookie. The session-id points to my db session store.

Answer (score 0):

**Really cool option:**

You can also run multiple distinct copies of Chrome by using the --user-data-dir= option.

– Dan D.

Comment: I agree. I gave it a plus +1 the moment I saw it. :)